# Rails 3 Add Foreign Key in Migration Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

Does anyone know of a way to create a foreign key in Rails 3 using migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[foreign_key_migrations](http://github.com/harukizaemon/redhillonrails/tree/master/foreign_key_migrations/),but I dont like that.

Answer (score 3):

the [foreigner gem](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) works well for me.  it adds a few methods to Rails migrations that allow easy foreign key creation and deletion:

example:

```
create_table :site_credit_payments do |t|
  t.decimal  :amount, precision: 8, scale: 2, nil: false
  t.string   :note, nil: true

  t.integer  :credit_account_id

  t.timestamps
end
add_foreign_key :site_credit_payments, :credit_accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're app has ActiveRecord::Migration (rails 3 apps do), use `add_foreign_key`. Documentation here:
http://araddconstraint.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html

Note that this is a plugin and not a part of Active Record.

Comment: This isn't part of AR it's a separate plugin.

Comment: I never said it was a part of AR.