# Problems using add_foreign_key in gem migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, rails-migrations

I found the answer here unhelpful: [Rails 3 Add Foreign Key in Migration Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631717/rails-3-add-foreign-key-in-migration-problems)

Implementing a namedspaced branch of the mailboxer gem I'm getting problems with the following:

```
add_foreign_key "mailboxer_receipts", "mailboxer_notifications", :name => "receipts_on_notification_id"
#Messages  
add_foreign_key "mailboxer_notifications", "mailboxer_conversations", :name => "notifications_on_conversation_id"
add_foreign_key :pairs, :programmers,
     :source_column => :second_id,
     :name => :fk_second_programmer
```

The full file is here: https://github.com/daveworth/mailboxer/blob/namedspaced/db/migrate/20110511145103_create_mailboxer.rb

The documentation here didn't help me:
http://araddconstraint.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html

The last foreign key appears to be copied from the documentation link above (???). The errors complained about the name of the foreign key which shouldn't matter - which makes me think it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed a gem called [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) as it wasn't listed as a dependency in [mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer). A fork of mailboxer fixes the namespace issue but mailboxer is dead and I recommend avoiding it.